# tasks that one wants somebody to perform

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

> We completely understand the **tasks that you want our company to perform** within the specified period.
>
> We completely understand **the tasks that our company is expected to perform** within the specified period.
>
> We completely understand **what you requested our company to perform** within the specified period.

Google did not show successful results for the phrase 'tasks that you want somebody to perform or implement' or for the similar phrases indicated above. However, I see nothing wrong with this phrase. I think it is fine or at least understandable. I want to make sure of that. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "understand *the* tasks"?  Are you wishing to confirm that you are very clear about which tasks need to be performed, or that your company has the skills and competence to perform those tasks?

Comment: @TRomano I mean both parts. The first part prevails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's fine and very clear.

Comment: There's no need for a "that" in the first phrase. (It's not wrong, but it's not necessary, either. The sentence might be a little easier to read without it.)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the desire is twofold, to confirm which tasks need to be performed, and to assure the recipient that the tasks will be performed properly, this choice edges out the others:

> We completely understand the tasks that our company is expected to
>   perform within the specified period

because "is expected to"  better expresses the idea of a business *agreement* than either "what you want" or "what you requested" -- assuming this letter is something like a "letter of intent".

Comment: Thank you. This is just business correspondence, informal conversation by e-mail before drawing up a letter a intent.